# regular expressions and ascii color escapes

Tags: javascript

I have a script that outputs code with lots of ASCII escape sequences pertaining to color (for example, `\033[91m` changes the color of the text to red when printed to a terminal). I'd like to try to output this to HTML, so I tried this:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\033[91m', 'g'),
                 '<span style="color:#ff0011">')
         /*.replace more such codes*/;
```

However, I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/[91m/`: Unterminated character class

How can I fix that?

Comment: You probably need to escape your [ because it has special meaning to a RegEx expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `'\033\\[91m'`. I.e. you have to escape the `'['` so that it doesn't think you are giving it a list of characters to match in that position.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `[` inside a character class like this:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\033[[]91m', 'g'),
             '<span style="color:#ff0011">');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wd5au/

Comment: It looks like working, but it's not. The '\' makes '033' disappear.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'blahblah\033[91mblahblah';
str = str.replace(new RegExp('[\\033[91m]+', 'g'),
             '<span style="color:#ff0011">');

alert(str);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8bybx/

Comment: also matches if the string is, say, '3m'.